# Component not unmounting when navigating between scenes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**EDIT**: I now suspect the issue is caused by the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538891/react-native-navigator-renderscene-called-multiple-times). I think that navigating away from a scene will render it again, thus keeping my component alive.

=========================

I am building a React Native component that listens for `NetInfo` changes and displays a modal dialog based on [react-native-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal).

This is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {NetInfo, View, Text, Button, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

export default class WifiCheckModal extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('WifiModal mounting');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(this.refreshConnectionStatus.bind(this), 500);
        NetInfo.addEventListener('change', this._handleConnectivityChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('WifiModal unmounting');
        NetInfo.removeEventListener('change', this._handleConnectivityChange);
        this.isAlive = false;
    }

    _handleConnectivityChange = (connectionStatus) => {
        console.log('IsConnected = ' + connectionStatus);
        // Need to handle 'WIFI' on Android and 'wifi' on iOS, so convert to lowercase.
        let isOnWifi = (connectionStatus.toLowerCase() === 'wifi');
        let shouldShowModal = !isOnWifi;

        if (this.state.showModal != shouldShowModal) {
            console.log('Changing modal state to ' + shouldShowModal + ' because connection is ' + connectionStatus);
            this.setState({showModal: !isOnWifi});
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal isVisible={this.state.showModal}>
                <View style={styles.modalContent}>
                    <Text>You must be connected to wifi to use this app.</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.refreshConnectionStatus.bind(this)}>
                        <View style={styles.button}>
                            <Text>Check again</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        );
    }

    refreshConnectionStatus() {
        NetInfo.fetch().then(connectionStatus => this._handleConnectivityChange(connectionStatus));
    }
}
```

I then use this component in the `render` method of other components that serve as scenes:

```
class SomeComponentScene extends Component {

    // ...

    render() {
        return (
            <View><WifiCheckModal /> ... </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The navigation code is found in my `index.js` (imported from `index.android.js`) and looks as follows:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
                console.log("Android back pressed");

                if (_navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length === 1  ) {
                    return false;
                }

                _navigator.pop();
                return true;
            });
        }

        return (<Navigator
            initialRoute={{ index: 0, name: 'Splash'}}
            renderScene={ this.navigateToScene }/>);
    }

    navigateToScene(route, navigator) {
        console.log("navigateToScene " + JSON.stringify(route));

        _navigator = navigator;

        if (route.name == 'Splash') {
            return <SplashScene
                navigator={navigator}
                onRequireAuthentication={() => {
                    navigator.replaceAtIndex({name: 'Login'}, 0);
                }}
                onNotRequireAuthentication={() => {
                    navigator.replaceAtIndex({name: 'List'}, 0);
                }}/>
        } else if (route.name == 'Login') {
            return <LoginScene
                navigator={navigator}
                onAuthenticationCompleted={() => {
                    navigator.replaceAtIndex({name: 'List'}, 0);
                }}/>
        } else if (route.name == 'List') {
            return <ListScene
                navigator={navigator}/>
        } else if (route.name == 'Add') {
            return <AddScene
                navigator={navigator}/>
        } else if (route.name == 'Chat') {
            return <ChatScene
                navigator={navigator}
                data={route.data}/>
        } else if (route.name == 'Map') {
            return <MapScene
                navigator={navigator}
                data={route.data}/>
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that the modal's `componentDidUnmount` is not always getting called when I move between scenes, leaving multiple listeners listening for `NetInfo` changes.

Are components not being unmounted when moving between scenes? Or perhaps there is something I'm doing that's keeping my component alive? Is there another way I should detect that my component is no longer in view and should thus unregister itself from `NetInfo`?

Or perhaps I'm worried for nothing and it's fine to have multiple listeners and they'll all be cleaned up eventually?

Comment: no you should clean up listeners. you should remove the components when not viewing. It sounds like there is a flag that is showing the elements or something instead of just unmounting them.

Comment: @JohnRuddell What flag should I be looking for? Shouldn't react be unmounting the (invisible) components during navigation?

Comment: it should. I dont know what is going on in your application since I dont see the navigation part. You need to make sure that you are rendering only the components that need to be rendered. the Unmount happens when you dont render a component that was rendered previously. So on a new render scene you need to only return the component you want to see. the others need to be omitted and that will kick off their unmount cycle

Comment: @JohnRuddell I use the modal component in multiple scenes. In a scene transition, my expectation was that it would unmount the modal of the old scene and mount the modal of the new scene. What I'm seeing instead is that it would sometime have two modals loaded at the same time. I can add my navigation code if you think the problem could lie there.

Comment: what is `_navigator`? also are you doing a `navigator.replace` anywhere? also you can clean up your code DRASTICALLY. [see my answer here for a better way to render multiple pages.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41113141/2733506)

Comment: @JohnRuddell `_navigator` is a global navigator object. I use `navigator.replaceAtIndex` in some locations. Could this be the problem? Also see the edit I placed at the top of my question - there's a React bug that causes `renderScene` to be called twice when navigating between scenes. Could this explain the problem? Your simplification is indeed simplifying :) I'll use it.